# Вытянут значения мультиполей формы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Упраздненный пример формы, где скрипт добавляет новые поля и потому они все одного класса.

```
<div class="forma">
   <div class="initials">
      <input type="text" name="first">
      <input type="text" name="last">
   </div>
   <div class="initials">
     <input type="text" name="first">
     <input type="text" name="lastn">
   </div>
   <div class="initials">
     <input type="text" name="first">
     <input type="text" name="last">
   </div>
</div>
```

Как вытянуть эти данные для последующего $ajax.post в виде массива

```
 {forma:[{firts: #, last: #}, {first: #, last:#}]}
```

сначала нужно создать массив, потом найти все элементы с классом **.initials**, в нем создать объект со свойствами **first & last** и этот объект push в массив? И у меня выводится массив, но элементы в нем **undefined**

```
var forma = new Array();        
var len = $('.initials').size() ;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var data = new Object();
        data.first = $('.initials input[name="first"]:eq(i)').val();
        data.last = $('.initials input[name="last"]:eq(i)').val();
        ingred.push(data);
     };
console.log(forma);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var forma = [];
$('.initials').each(function(index){
  forma.push({
     first: $('input[name="first"]', this).val(),
     last: $('input[name="last"]', this).val()
  });
});

// $(селектор, контекст);
```

1. Без указания контекста каждый раз результат будет для всего документа.
2. Рекомендуют использовать литеральную нотацию.

Comment: спасибо за ответ и совет